# My regular expression to clean up punctuation does not work

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean up a CSV file with punctuation. So far I have been able to remove digits using `myFile = re.sub("\d+", "", str(myFile))`
however, I am unable to remove punctuation.

I have tried the following but I get an error that says invalid syntax:

```
chars = re.escape(string.punctuation)
myFile = re.sub (r '['+chars+']',' ',str(myFile))
```

When I use

```
myFile = re.sub ('@,#,?',' ',str(myFile))
```

Nothing is removed.

I have seen several posts but still can't seem to get this right.

Comment: `myFile = re.sub (r'[@#?]', '',str(myFile))`

Answer (score 0):

```
myFile = re.sub (r '['+chars+']',' ',str(myFile))
#                 ^ remove that space
```

You can also remove `r`, as it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFile = re.sub ('[^\s\w]+',' ',str(myFile))
```

This will find all punctuation and a substitute nothing

Comment: Thank you! But how do I put space between words? Some of the words are bunched together? To be exact, the words withing a website url are bunched together. example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595773/my-regular-expression-to-clean-up-punctuation-does-not-work/33595824#33595824.

Comment: if you are replacing a punctuation with a space try  myFile = re.sub ('[^\s\w]',' ',str(myFile))..note i replace ''  with ' ' in this command line

Comment: slight edit done again..I am assuming you might  have  a situation with several punctuation together

Comment: or not.. e.g. `"word, word"`. The question is unclear on this issue, just leave it like that.